# Disambiguate [indian] (or merge it into [india])

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

The [indian](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian) tag has 20 questions and no tag wiki or excerpt, and (as far as I can see) except for [How did Pocahontas die?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/17620/12622), all questions are about India's (former) inhabitants or languages, for which we already have the much more popular [india](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) tag (345 questions).

If we want a separate tag to distinguish questions about the various Indian languages, I think [indian-languages](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-languages) would be clearer, cf. [latin-language](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-language) and [english-language](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-language).

Any thoughts or objections?

Comment: One thought: excellent discovery, analysis, rationale, solution, my endorsement.With perhaps one tiny improvement request: "India" had and has many languages? (Tiny, as if one reads the tag as ["_an_ Indian language"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_languages) we might be conetnt with that or refine further (linguistics)?

Comment: @LаngLаngС excellent point, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. Probably the right thing to do would be either to merge "indian" into "india", or retag them all. I don't think "Indian" will be particularly useful as a synonym going forward, but a merge would avoid bumping all 20 questions.

Comment: ...However, I went ahead and retagged the one about Pocahantas, since there's no way to avoid having to do that one.

Comment: @T.E.D. the merge is mainly to prevent users from recreating the tag.

Comment: I'm not super worried about that. I think it was created by the Pocahontas author almost 10 years ago, and the only reason any of the others used it was because it existed. If it were to cease to exist, someone typing it in would get an auto-complete for "india", and I'd (naively?) think almost certainly would be satisfied with that.

Comment: I *suppose* an argument could be made for leaving it as a synonym for [tag:native-americans] (since that's what it got created for), but I'm not sure I like that idea.

Answer (score 5):

I just reviewed the 23 current questions under the tag, and all of them are either suitable for retagging with [india](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) or [native-americans](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/native-americans).

A tag which is so ambiguous as to apply equally to two unrelated cultures, nations, or groups in two separate parts of the world is, according to definitions, an unacceptable tag.

What I propose is to burninate [indian](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian) and retag appropriately to [india](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) or [native-americans](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/native-americans) as applicable.

I agree with T.E.D. that keeping the tag, even as a synonym, is problematic. The term is inherently ambiguous and is likely to lead to misuse.

Comment: Maybe also blacklist [tag:indian] ? I think there's a high chance of someone re-creating it. A synonym of [tag:american-indian] to [tag:native-american] would also guide askers to the correct tag.